# Recovering "About Me" info from UPSA Profile DB backup

Tags: 2013, backup, mysites, userprofiles, contentdb-backup

When trying to recover the "About Me" info from the UPSA Profile DB - I'm getting a "There is a compatibility range mismatch between the web server..." error.

Is there an alternative way of going about this without any sort of upgrade/updates?

Thanks in advanced to the brains in the community!